# How can I convert a pandas DataFrame to an arrayed representation?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

My `Y` is

```
       AdoptionSpeed
0                  2
1                  0
2                  3
3                  2
4                  2
5                  2
6                  1
7                  3
8                  1
9                  4
...              ...
14987              0
14988              2
14989              4
14990              3
14991              4
14992              3

[14993 rows x 1 columns]
```

I want to convert this to be something like...

```
        0   1   2   3
0       1   1   0   0
1       0   0   0   0
2       1   1   1   0
....
14991   1   1   1   1
```

So basically all entries with 2 become `[1  1  0  0]` and so on.

Comment: probably want to do something with pd.DataFrame.as_matrix() and then np.binary_repr()

Comment: so max value is 15 i suppose?

Comment: Values are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same like my previous solution

```
pd.DataFrame([np.ones(x) for x in df['AdoptionSpeed']]).fillna(0).astype(int)
Out[70]: 
   0  1  2  3
0  1  1  0  0
1  0  0  0  0
2  1  1  1  0
3  1  1  0  0
4  1  1  0  0
5  1  1  0  0
6  1  0  0  0
7  1  1  1  0
8  1  0  0  0
9  1  1  1  1
```

---

Or more like `numpy` broadcast : should be faster than for loop

```
x=df.AdoptionSpeed.max()
pd.DataFrame((df.AdoptionSpeed.values[:,None]>np.arange(x)).astype(int))
Out[81]: 
   0  1  2  3
0  1  1  0  0
1  0  0  0  0
2  1  1  1  0
3  1  1  0  0
4  1  1  0  0
5  1  1  0  0
6  1  0  0  0
7  1  1  1  0
8  1  0  0  0
9  1  1  1  1
```

Answer (score 1):

bin is your friend!!:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'AdoptionSpeed': np.random.randint(16, size=10)})
df = df.AdoptionSpeed.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(bin(x)[2:]))).fillna(0).astype(int)
print(df)
```

output:

```
   0  1  2  3
0  1  1  1  1
1  1  0  1  0
2  1  1  1  0
3  1  0  1  0
4  1  0  0  0
5  1  0  0  1
6  1  1  0  1
7  1  1  1  0
8  1  1  1  0
9  1  0  0  1
```